# Co-existince of Kie-Server alongwith JBPM Console 7.2.0

Tags: jboss, wildfly, jbpm, kie

I built three separate war files, namely, jbpm-console, kie-server, and jbpm-casemgmt using the below ant commands.

```
ant install.jBPM-console.into.jboss
ant install.kie-server.into.jboss
ant install.jBPM-casemgmt.into.jboss
```

When I deploy all separately on Wildfly server, each of the deployments are working. But in the same deployment directory kie-server could not coexist along with jbpm-console or casemgmt.

Without kie-server, I could not execute the process.

Did anyone get through these kind of issues so far with the newest release of JBPM 7.2.0?

Comment: what exception you encounter when you deploy all three war files at a time ?

Comment: Its says something like duplicate dependencies. I stopped using it for the moment becasue of multiple issues and lack of good documentation. Thats why I could not give exact specification of errors. I suspect jBPM Console is having some dependencies in its war package containing the kie-server. So when I deploy the kie-server its pointing duplicate package. Later when I took the developer build of Redhat JBPM Suite, these type of problems resolved.